# Proper header file syntax

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to understand when it is required to declare a function in a header file when inheriting methods from a parent class.

For example lets say I have the following class:

```
class parent{
public:
    virtual void foo()= 0;
}
```

Lets say I have a child class that inherits from parent do I have to also declare foo in child's header file or can I simply define the method in the source file for child?

Would the following delaration be incorrect?

Headerfile:

```
class child : public parent{
}
```

Classfile:

```
child::foo(){
// do something
}
```

Comment: `foo` should be declared `virtual`.  Aside from that, if you're overriding `foo` (which you'd all but have to, since it's pure virtual), then you need to declare it in the child class as part of the class definition.

Comment: `foo()` should also be declared `public` as otherwise it is inaccessible to the classes which inherit from the `parent`.

Comment: C++ actually allows private virtual functions (and even lets you override them).  Usually it's to let derived classes specify some functionality expected by the base class without letting it be part of the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to declare `foo()` in the child's class definition or its header.  It is inherited automatically - that's what inheritance means.  (Of course, the function would have to be `public` rather than `private` in the base class (`parent`), but that's a minor peccadillo.)

You simply define the method in the source file for the child class.

Comment: This isn't true. He won't be able to instantiate `child` unless he declares it as non-pure virtual.

Comment: g++ failed: `error: no ‘void child::foo()’ member function declared in class ‘child’`

Answer (score 1):

Non virtual methods from a base class are inherited in child class so you do not need to define or declare them  again in child class, A non virtual method called on an derived class object will simply call the method defined in Base class(provided access specifier rules allow you to)

if you declare an method from base class again in Derived class then it declares a new method in derived class which *hides* all the base class methods with the same name. This is called as **Function Hiding**.

Good Read:

**[What's the meaning of, Warning: Derived::f(char) hides Base::f(double)?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9)**

In case of virtual methods you do not need to declare the Base class method again in Child class, You just need to provide a definition. This is called as **Function Overidding**.

Answer (score 0):

Header file:

```
class Class : public Parent {

public:
    void myMethod();
}
```

Source file:

```
void Class::myMethod(){

}
```